# Using Google Play Services to authenticate with App Engine using OAuth2

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-play-services

Google Play Services [recently released a new OAuth 2.0 API](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html) for easy OAuth 2.0 authentication.  I was hoping to be able to use this in concurrence with an App Engine application.

I haven't been able to find any way to do this however, and I'm not sure how I should be querying App Engine after I get the token.  Is this something that I should be added to the headers whenever I query App Engine?  Will OAuth 2.0 even work with App Engine?  Should I be using a specific scope?  If possible, I'd like to use the scope that gives a profile: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Or if there's no way to authenticate on an App Engine service like this just yet?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to get the user's profile from an Android application, you can directly query this from Google without your App Engine application involved anywhere.

Comment: I want to authenticate the user against the App Engine code so that they can perform actions as an authenticated user.

Comment: So your App Engine application stores any private data of the user and he can log in there with his Google account? Or should the user log in to your App Engine application so this application can access data of the user using the Google API?

Comment: I just want to do basic authentication.  I don't need to store any extra information about the user (name would be nice, but not required).  App Engine allows for Google Account authentication and the new Google Play services looks like it would make Google Account authentication through OAuth2 very easy.  Maybe I'm missing something, here, though.

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

OAuth2 authentication to GAE only works with GAE endpoints (AFAIK), which is not available to everyone yet. You can sign up for the trusted tester program, you might get access. You can use ClientLogin to get an authentication token via the standard `AccountManager` (use the 'ah' service name) to authenticate users, there are multiple examples/blog about this. However, this is deprecated and will stop working in about a year or so.

Comment: So what's the "correct" way to do this, right now, from an Android app?  Or for that matter, an iPhone one?  (Basically, I'm looking for one that doesn't involve an App Engine Connected Android app, because A) that doesn't work for iPhone and B) that doesn't work for python App Engine, which I'm using).

Comment: 'Connected apps' seem to have been silently deprecated, as is GWT. Endpoints look pretty nice, and that will probably be the recommended technology when released (works for iPhone, Windows, etc. client libraries are automatically generated). For now, I'd say use ClientLogin which is seamless on Android and doesn't require entering a password or using a WebView to get a token (on iPhone you will need them to provide the password though). Or write it yourself based on profile info with something like: http://alex.cloudware.it/2012/02/simple-auth-on-app-engine-without.html